# Не получается получить TextBox.Text в WPF через DataContext

Tags: c#

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Class2 cl = new Class2();
            cl.AAA = "text";
        }
    }

    public class Class2 : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        private string aaa;

        public string AAA
        {
            get { return aaa; }
            set
            {
                aaa = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Class2 x:Key="Resource1"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox DataContext="{StaticResource Resource1}" Text="{Binding AAA, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" Height="50"/>
        <Button Name="Button1" Width="200" Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,200" Click="Button1_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Знаете почему такое получается? При привязке чего либо вы должны работать именно с этим объектом. При инициализации повторно класса вы создаете новую его копию, новый объект, который не как уже не связан с ранее привязанным классом. То есть при нажатие кнопки у вас попросту появляется новая копия класса с измененным свойством. Я советую вам отказаться от указании DataContext через XAML и сделать это в коде, установив DataContext на все окно.

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам! Уже несколько дней мучаюсь. Начинающий программист, но пока бездарный.

Answer (score 0):

Я изменил код следующим образом и установил DataContext в codebehind

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Class2 cl = new Class2();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GridName.DataContext = cl;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cl.AAA = "text";
        }
    }

    public class Class2 : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        private string aaa;

        public string AAA
        {
            get { return aaa; }
            set
            {
                aaa = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Class2 x:Key="Resource1"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Name="GridName">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding AAA, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" Height="50"/>
        <Button Name="Button1" Width="200" Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,200" Click="Button1_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Если вы учитесь, то советую с самого начала привыкать к MVVM подходу, который разделяет логику на не связанные особо друг с другом слои. То есть ваш код не должен вообще знать какие есть контролы у него во View (XAML окно). Не обращайтесь по именам к контролам через код. Вам тут достаточно задать вместо `GridName.DataContext = cl;` просто `DataContext = cl;`. Это задаст DataContext всему окну. Еще лучше задать DataContext в App, переписав инициализацию окна. P.S. Старый "Ответ" стоит удалить (должна быть кнопка под ним).